# Dynamic Django Filter with Prerequisite

Tags: python, django

I know how to typically do dynamic filters in Django using **kwargs, however since I am relatively new to python I can't figure out how to do something slightly different than some of the other related questions that have been asked here.

I want to dynamically apply the same filter to different model children. I realize this is not correct, but it should give you the gist of what I want to do:

```
self.type = object.__class__.__name__
if self.type = 'Running':    
    kwargs = '%s__%s__%s' % ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
elif self.type = 'Jumping':
    kwargs = '%s__%s' % ('alpha', 'beta')
elif self.type = 'Playing':
    kwargs = '%s' % ('alpha',)

self.customers = Fest.objects.filter(foo__kwargs = object)
self.customers = Fest.objects.filter(bar__kwargs = object)
self.customers = Jest.objects.filter(baz__kwargs = object)
```

===================EDIT===================

I apologize for not stating the original question more clearly. I'm not sure if this will make it any better though:

I have MANY different objects and object children to filter based on these common argument scenarios. For that reason, I do not want to individually define a dictionary for each variant of kwargs as @S.Lott has graciously suggested. It would be just as repetitive as typing in the arguments for each filter.

I am simply trying to figure out the most efficient method for doing this. It seems there must be a better way in this particular case than to define multiple argument dictionaries which would repeat the `('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')` declaration every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function's arguments **are** a dictionary.

Build your filter like this.

```
def filter_with_prefix( self, prefix, object ):

    if self.type = 'Running':    
        kwargs = { '%s__%s__%s__%s' % (prefix, 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma') : object }
    elif self.type = 'Jumping':
        kwargs = { '%s__%s__%s' % (prefix, 'alpha', 'beta') : object }
    elif self.type = 'Playing':
        kwargs = { '%s__%s' % (prefix, 'alpha',) : object }
    return kwargs
```

Use it like this

```
f1= some_object.filter_with_prefix( 'foo', object )
self.customers = Fest.objects.filter(**f1)
f2= some_object.filter_with_prefix( 'bar', object )
self.customers = Fest.objects.filter(**f2)
f3= some_object.filter_with_prefix( 'baz', object )
self.customers = Fest.objects.filter(**f3)
```

Since all you can ever do is build a dictionary, it appears that your problem boils down to building appropriate dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstand what I am trying to do. I know how to do a typical **kwargs filter. Please pay close attention to how I want to apply those 'kwargs' to different children dynamically.

Comment: @Sunsu: Please pay close attention to the way Python works.  There are probably dozens of ways to build the required dictionary.

Comment: I understand that I can build an individual dictionary for each variant of kwargs I want to pass, however that does not answer my question.

Comment: @Sunsun: Then you should conssider clarifying and correcting your question so that it's clear what you **do** want that's different from this.

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get back to my comp. On my phone at the moment. Thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: Your suggestion worked by passing the function to the filter like this:

`Fest.objects.filter(**filter_with_prefix(self, 'foo', object))`



I forgot that functions are first-class objects in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sunsu: That does not depend on function's being first-class objects.  That's just an ordinary function call that returns an ordinary dictionary which is simply passed to the filter function.  Nothing special happening there at all.